# How to embed LiveGraph in ipywidgets Output?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, output, ipywidgets

By using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952210/11885372) to produce a LiveGraph and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668721/11885372) to update variables to a thread, I was able to generate a graph that updates itself each second and whose amplitude is determined by a slider (code below). Both answers were incredibly helpful!

```
%matplotlib notebook
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
'''#################### Live Graph ####################''' 
# Create a new class which is a live graph
class LiveGraph(object):
    def __init__(self, baseline):
        self.x_data, self.y_data = [], []
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.line, = plt.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data)
        self.animation = FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.update, interval=1200)
        # define variable to be updated as a list
        self.baseline = [baseline]
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.th = Thread(target=self.thread_f, args = (self.baseline,), daemon=True)
        # start thread
        self.th.start()
    
    def update_baseline(self,baseline):
        # updating a list updates the thread argument
        with self.lock:
            self.baseline[0] = baseline
    
    # Updates animation
    def update(self, frame):
        self.line.set_data(self.x_data, self.y_data)
        self.figure.gca().relim()
        self.figure.gca().autoscale_view()
        return self.line,
    
    def show(self):
        plt.show()
    
    # Function called by thread that updates variables
    def thread_f(self, base):
        x = 0
        while True:
            self.x_data.append(x)
            x += 1
            self.y_data.append(base[0])    
            time.sleep(1)  
            
'''#################### Slider ####################'''            
# Function that updates baseline to slider value
def update_baseline(v):
    global g
    new_value = v['new']
    g.update_baseline(new_value)
    
slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=10,
    min=0,
    max=200,
    step=1,
    description='value:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)
slider.observe(update_baseline, names = 'value')

'''#################### Display ####################''' 

display(slider)
g = LiveGraph(slider.value)
```

Still, I would like to put the graph inside a bigger interface which has other widgets. It seems that I should put the LiveGraph inside the [Output widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html#Output-widgets:-leveraging-Jupyter%27s-display-system), but when I replace the 'Display section' of my code by the code shown below, no figure is displayed.

```
out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
with out:
    g = LiveGraph(slider.value)

vbox = widgets.VBox([slider,out], align_self='stretch',justify_content='center')       
vbox
```

Is there a way to embed this LiveGraph in the output widget or in a [box widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Container/Layout-widgets)?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the matplotlib notebook magic with a display ipywidget, can you get the code to work without it, with `%matplotlib inline` instead?

Comment: If I change to `inline`, the animation doesn't work, so nothing is plotted.
Apparently, FuncAnimation in jupyter notebooks needs the notebook backend to work, as cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43447370/11885372)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by avoiding using FuncAnimation and the Output widget altogether while keeping my backend as inline.
Also changing from matplotlib to bqplot was essential!

The code is shown below (be careful because, as it is, it keeps increasing a list).

Details of things I tried:

I had no success updating the graph by a thread when using the Output Widget (tried clearing axes with `ax.clear`, redrawing the whole plot - since it is a static backend - and also using `clear_output()` [command](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html#)).
Also, ipywidgets does not allow placing a matplotlib figure straight inside a container, but it does if it is a bqplot figure!

I hope this answer helps anyone trying to integrate ipywidgets with a plot that constantly updates itself within an interface full of other widgets.

```
%matplotlib inline
import bqplot.pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
t, value = [], []
lines = plt.plot(x=t, y=value)

# Function that updates baseline to slider value
def update_baseline(v):
    global base, lock
    with lock:
        new_value = v['new']
        base = new_value
    
slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=10,
    min=0,
    max=200,
    step=1,
    description='value:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)
base = slider.value
slider.observe(update_baseline, names = 'value')

def thread_f():
    global t, value, base, lines
    x = 0
    while True:
        t.append(x)
        x += 1
        value.append(base)
        with lines.hold_sync():
            lines.x = t
            lines.y = value
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
lock = Lock()
th = Thread(target=thread_f, daemon=True)
# start thread
th.start()

vbox = widgets.VBox([slider,fig], align_self='stretch',justify_content='center')       
vbox
```

P.S. I'm new to using threads, so be careful as the thread may not be properly stopped with this code.

```
bqplot==0.12.29
ipywidgets==7.6.3
numpy==1.20.2
```